# Generalized Ladyzhenskaya inequality for $n=2$.

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations

Is there a way to prove the following generalized Ladyzhenskaya inequality for $n=2$? The statement goes as follows:

Let $n = 2$ and $0 < p < \infty$. Then, for all $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$, we have
$$||f||^{p+2}_{L^{p+2}} \leq C ||f||_{L^2}^{2} ||\nabla f||_{L^2}^p$$
with the constant $C$ uniform in $f$.

We know that for $p = 2$, this reduces to the usual Ladyzhenskaya inequality:

$$||f||_{L^4}^2 \leq ||u||_{L^2} ||\nabla f||_{L^2} $$

and a proof of this can be readily found online, as such in http://willkwon.dothome.co.kr/index.php/archives/493. However, I find it hard to generalize this proof for $L^{p+2}$. Although this might follow from the general class of Gagliardo–Nirenberg interpolation inequalities, I was thinking if there is a somewhat elementary way of doing this.

Any help would be appreciated!